# Evaluating a definite integral through special functions

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions

I'm working with several definite integrals and  I arises the following problem. I'm going to try explain in the most generic way possible:

Consider this definite integral

\begin{equation}\label{one}\int_a^b f(x)\,g(x)\,dx\hspace{6cm}(1)\end{equation}

where $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R^+}$ is bounded or not and the functions $f$ and $g$ are two consecutive functions of the list $$\ln(\ln\,x),\ln(x),x^\alpha,e^x,e^{e^x}$$

Then, performing a suitable change of variable, one can express integral $(1)$ in terms of Gamma or Incomplete Gamma functions.

Well, my question is what can I do when $f$ and $g$ are not consecutive functions in the above list, in fact, are alternate functions, that is $\ln(\ln\,x)$ and $x^\alpha$ or $\ln(x)$ and $e^x$ ...

On the one hand, I wonder if there is any special function which has an integral representation with this  kind of functions in the integrand.

On the other hand, I also wonder if there is any other way to evaluate this integral.

Any help or suggestion is wellcomend.

Comment: If $(a,b)$ are general, you are in fact asking for the indefinite integrals. There are $10$ cases in your question, please be explicit about those that you can already handle and those that you need to (there is no generic solution). Also specify if $\alpha$ is rational.

Comment: $(a,b)$ can be considered in the positive real axis

Comment: $\alpha$ is a real parameter.

Comment: Ask Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 1):

For the case of 
$$I=\int \log(x)\,e^x\,dx$$ one integration by parts will give
$$I=e^x \log (x)-\text{Ei}(x)$$ where appears the exponential integral function.

$$J=\int x^a \log (\log (x))\,dx=\frac{x^{a+1} \log (\log (x))-\text{Ei}((a+1) \log (x))}{a+1}$$

These special functions are precisely introduced for such cases.